# How to setup SQLite for android/ios device

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I need to setup SQLite for my Ionic(cordova) + Angular App. App in browser works, but when I build for device I have problems with creation DB.

```
  createDatabase() {

      return this.plt.ready().then(() => {
        return this.sqlite.create({
          name: this.dbName,
          location: this.dbLocation
        }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => { <-- problem is here
          this.database = db;
          console.log('Database CREATED:', db);

          return db;
        })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error opening database:', error);
            return null;
          });
      });
  }
```

"cordova-android": "^11.0.0",
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.36.0",
"@ionic-native/sqlite": "^5.36.0",
"@ionic/angular": "^6.1.9",

May be i need to add smt permissions?

Comment: What problem do you have? Is there an error message that you could post?